# Where clause in windows phone using sql server compact tool 3.5

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-phone-7, where-clause

I am trying to query the database to get the result if the condition of the where clause is correct but I think i queried the wrong way. It has an error of cannot implicitly convert type string  to PhoneApp.Budgets. What have i done wrong here. Below is my code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(expenseDate.Value.ToString());
monthsGet.Text = dt.Month.ToString();
yearsGet.Text = dt.Year.ToString();
string monthBud = monthsGet.Text;

IQueryable<Budgets> bud = from MonthBud in c.Budgets where MonthBud = monthBud select MonthBud;

budgetAmount.Text= bud.ToString();
```

Comment: Obvious error is you're using `=` instead of `==`. Then you may need to access the property `where MonthBud.InterestedProperty == monthBud`. Fill in your "InterestedProperty".

Comment: Let me know what is Budgets and MonthBud in your code.

Comment: @Jaihind Budgets is the database table's name and monthBud is the variable which value is the month from monthsGet.Text;

Comment: @SriramSakthivel MonthBud is a one of the field in the table of Budgets. What do you mean by interestedproperty. Could you give me an exmaple? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in comment 'Budgets' is the database table's, means its a business logic class. And MonthBud is a field of table which is string type. That's why you getting error. May this will help you.

```
var bud = from MonthBud in c.Budgets where MonthBud = monthBud select MonthBud;
budgetAmount.Text= bud.ToString();
```